# CRLF with perl -pi -e

Tags: perl

In a perl program I have, I call out to make in-place edits to a file with restricted privileges:

```
for my $file (@files) {
    `sudo perl -pi -e 's/foo(.?foo2)/bar\$1/m' '$file'`;
}
```

There may be a line break between foo and foo2, but the files use CRLF as their line break. How can I match CRLF in a -pi command with s///m or s///s?

Answer (score 2):

How about `\s*`? Or if you feel like being specific `[\r\n]{0,2}`. The former matches 0 or more whitespace, the latter 0 to 2 line feed or carriage return. You also need to not read the file in line-by-line mode, using `-0777`.

Perhaps a better solution than to run a number of system commands as one-liners, is to create a script file that takes a list of files, such as

```
system(qw(sudo perl -0777 -pi script.pl), @files);
```

And the script file contains only your substitution:

```
s/foo(?=\s*foo2)/bar/m;
```

I also replaced the backreference `$1` with a look-ahead assertion. Note that I recommend that you run this without the `-i` switch or with the `-i.bak` backup option enabled until you know it works as intended with your files.

Comment: The [`\R` backslash sequence](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html#%5cR) will match anything that is considered linebreak-y by Unicode, but may be too diffuse for this problem.

Comment: @amon Unless there is significant trailing whitespace, `\s*` should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Before I answer your question, let's address two things.

First of all, you have a useless use of backticks. Use `system` instead.

```
for my $file (@files) {
    system("sudo perl ...");
}
```

Second of all, you are not properly converting the contents of `$file` into a shell literal. Consider what would happen if `$file` contains a single-quote. Fix:

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );
for my $file (@files) {
    system(shell_quote('sudo', 'perl', ..., $file));
}
```

or you can avoid the shell entirely:

```
for my $file (@files) {
    system('sudo', 'perl', ..., $file);
}
```

---

On to your question.

`-p` causes Perl to wrap the program with

```
while (<>) {
   ... -e ...
} continue {
   print;
}
```

As such,

```
/foo(\r\nfoo2)/
```

or the more flexible

```
/foo(\s*\nfoo2)/
```

can't possibly match since you haven't read `foo2` yet. You could cause `<>` to read the entire file by executing `local $/;` first, which can be done by adding `-0777` to get

```
$/ = undef;
while (<>) {
   ...[ code from -e ]...
} continue {
   print;
}
```

So what you need is:

```
for my $file (@files) {
    system('sudo', 'perl', '-i', '-0777pe', 's/foo(\s*\nfoo2)/bar$1/', $file);
}
```

Or you could even avoid the `for` loop and use

```
system('sudo', 'perl', '-i', '-0777pe', 's/foo(\s*\nfoo2)/bar$1/', @files);
```